# Какие полезные видео курсы/туториалы есть для новичков в создании игр на Unity3D (На анг. или рус.)?

Tags: unity3d, видео

Я программирую на Unity3d (Примерно месяц), и интересно, какие есть хорошие гайды, курсы и/или туториалы. Можно на любых платформах, к примеру:

- Udemy
- Youtube
- И другие

Заранее спасибо, очень интересно посмотреть :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прекрасная платформа степик, на которой ты смог бы изучить unity 3d и многое другое. Сам тоже пользуюсь частенько, данной платформой.  Для телефонов есть отдельное приложение. Единственно что на ней как платные так и бесплатные курсы.
https://stepik.org/course/51211/promo

Comment: Здравствуйте :)
Спасибо Вам за сайт! Я позже посмотрю на степик видео по Unity. А пока подожду, что другие напишут, хочется посмотреть, может есть ещё видео/сайты/форумы. %)